# Ubuntu/Kubuntu 16.04.1 installation in VirtualBox

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, kubuntu

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 16.04.1 on a virtual machine (I'm using VirtualBox). When I boot from the disk image Ubuntu begins to load and then I get this screen:
[image: scrambled screen]

It looks like it's loading but the display is not working properly (the pink blob is my mouse pointer, only very large and pink).

I also tried installing Ubuntu 16.04.1 and I get a very similar result:
[image: scrambled screen 2]

Am I missing something in VirtualBox? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the "extras" in VB?

Comment: I installed all the extras. I got 14.04 installed fine, it just seems to happen with 16.04

Comment: What version of Virtualbox have you installed?  Is it the one in the repos or have you downloaded the latest one from the virtualbox site?

Comment: It should be the latest one (I'm running it from windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. When you see the display(s) you describe, hit the `right-ctrl and f1` keys, then the `right-ctrl and f7` keys. This should straighten out the display so that you can properly install Ubuntu/Kubuntu.

Cheers, Al

Comment: this worked! however I did `right-ctrl + f1` -> `right-ctrl + f7` -> `right-ctrl + f1`

Answer (score 1):

This should not happen and seems to be a bug in virtualbox. Consider to write a bug report.
If you are using two displays, you may shut off one of them, that may be a first aid.
I suggest to install the guest additions, they contain a video driver. To be able to do this, switch to console/tty0 of your virtual ubuntu. It is accessable with your host key +F1. Normally the host key is the right control key.

Insert guest additions using virtualbox menu.
mount cd with

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
```

go to /mnt and show content

```
cd /mnt
ls
```

Install guest additions with

```
sudo sh ./VirtualBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

EDIT: Did you activate 2d or 3d acceleration in VirtualBox? It is an experimental feature and can cause some strange errors.