# How to troubleshoot this error when Ubuntu does not install on VirtualBox?

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, 32-bit

I downloaded the Ubuntu 16.04 i386.iso file from the website and tried to load it on the VirtualBox but it does not get installed and displays this window. Can someone help?

[image: Image of the problem]

Comment: Have you installed the Extension Pack?

Comment: What is the Extension Pack?

Comment: If you're asking then you didn't :) https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads Select the package according to your Virtualbox version. The host OS doesn't matter in this case, the Extension Pack is to be opened by the installed Virtuabox itself. Install it and try again, change (improve, recommended) the graphics settings if needed before running the installer / live session.

Comment: Oops! It was a bug! I got the answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/820099/ubuntu-kubuntu-16-04-1-installation-in-virtualbox?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As memory serves me, switching TTY's should fix the problem.

To fix your video problem, hit the  <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, followed by <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. It's a bug.

On a Mac, you may have to <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>host_key</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>